# Mongodb got stack overflow by unmarshal

Tags: go, mgo

I want to use mongodb in golang and wrote an sample application:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "labix.org/v2/mgo"
    "labix.org/v2/mgo/bson"
    "os"
)

type Session struct {
    Id   bson.ObjectId          `bson:"_id"`
    Data map[string]interface{} `bson:"data"`
}

func (rcv *Session) SetBSON(raw bson.Raw) error {
    return raw.Unmarshal(rcv)
}


type Authen struct {
    Name  string `bson:"name"`
    Email string `bson:"email"`
}

func main() {
    uri := "mongodb://localhost/"
    if uri == "" {
        fmt.Println("no connection string provided")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    sess, err := mgo.Dial(uri)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Can't connect to mongo, go error %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer sess.Close()

    sess.SetSafe(&mgo.Safe{})
    collection := sess.DB("test").C("sess")

    a := &Authen{Name: "Cormier", Email: "cormier@example.com"}
    s := &Session{}
    s.Id = bson.NewObjectId()
    s.Data = make(map[string]interface{})
    s.Data["logged"] = a

    err = collection.Insert(s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Can't insert document: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    c := &Session{}
    c.Id = bson.NewObjectId()
    c.Data = make(map[string]interface{})

    err = sess.DB("test").C("sess").Find(bson.M{}).One(c)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("got an error finding a doc %v\n")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

}
```

Insert into mongodb works like a charm, but to unmarshal back to reference I've got following panic:

```
runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit
fatal error: stack overflow

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x6d84d9)
        c:/go/src/runtime/panic.go:491 +0xad
runtime.newstack()
        c:/go/src/runtime/stack.c:784 +0x5ef
runtime.morestack()
        c:/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:324 +0x86
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This logic introduces an infinite recursion:

```
func (rcv *Session) SetBSON(raw bson.Raw) error {
    return raw.Unmarshal(rcv)
}
```

`Session` implements the [Setter](http://gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Setter) interface, which means its unmarshaling happens via its `SetBSON` method, which is implemented by asking the `bson` package to unmarshal itself, which will do that by calling its `SetBSON` method. This never ends, until the stack space is over.

The solution is, of course, to not implement custom unmarshaling of `Session` by just asking the `bson` package to unmarshal it again.

Comment: I deleted the implemented interface and when I run the application, I've got not what I want. `&{ObjectIdHex("54f9ba7d5042ea0af0000001") map[logged:map[name:Cormier email:cormier@example.com]]}`. I expect here by map[logged] not a map as result, but athen based type. How can I do that?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do that, but this is unrelated to the original question, and this comment box is not a reasonable place to explain it.

Comment: ok, thanks I will open a new question about it. Thanks gustavo.